# Magento 1.9 menu and products stock problem

Tags: magento-1.9, database, reindex, product-reindexing

I have a problem with a **Magento 1.9.1.1** store: categories menu in header disappears and in the meantime all the product stock seems to be unavailable. The strange thing is that the two problems occur at the same time.

I've explored the site and there's a module installed that runs asynchronous re-index every minute, and the problem seems to appear every minute, so I think the 2 problems are related.

My question is: what can possibly cause this problem? A database lock during re-index on the stock information so that Magento can't read data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you find table `index_process` in db and set `status` column as `pending` for all rows and index again from admin. ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat yes I tried but no luck

Comment: If anyone is having a similar issue, I noticed that when menu and product stock disappear is because the PHP autoloader loads some classes instead of others...
I have tried to deploy the site on another server and it works, so it's an environment issue, not a Magento one.